# Ruby Multiple threads reading from same hash

Tags: ruby, multithreading, hash, concurrency

A hash in ruby was populated ( in a single-threaded fashion), and once all the required values are populated, multiple processes with multiple threads ( e.g. 3 processes with 10 threads each) trying to read values from the hash in parallel.

Questions:

1. Can threads truly read values from hash in parallel ? or will they be blocked like a sequential access?
2. Is it better to have a local copy of hash for each thread vs. all of them accessing same object?
3. What are the best practices for multi-threaded reads?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As long as all you're doing is reading and not writing then it is considered thread safe, however if you have to write at any point (when there is reading going on) then it wouldn't be considered thread safe.

1. They should not be blocked
2. If you're reading then this should be a non-issue to keep a single hash.
3. See 2

Remember, if you have to do any write operations then you would need to pause the read until the write has finished.